# How to check if an array of arrays contains an empty array in my selector?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a selector that is selecting the array of arrays

```
export const doesArrayContainEmptyArray = createSelector(
    getTestState,
    (state: TestState) => state.selectedTemplate?.plate.map(p => p.plateTest.map(pt => pt?.columnValues))
);
```

In my .ts file I have an observable that calls the selector

```
    doesArrayContainEmptyArray$ = this.store.pipe(select(doesArrayContainEmptyArray));
```

I console logged it out like this

```
    this.doesArrayContainEmptyArray$.subscribe(a=> console.log("array: ", a));
```

In the console I see:

```
[Array(4)]
   0: Array(4)
      0: ['test']
      1: []
      2: []
      3: []
```

I want the selector to return false if it the array contains an array that is empty and true if all inner arrays have values

Answer (score 1):

general solution:

```
arr.every(subarr => subarr.length)
```

[image: click here to see example of work]

Comment: What is every? a ramda function?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the javascript array operation **some** to get the value

For additional operations [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Since you have your function named **doesArrayContainEmptyArray** we want to return true when the array of arrays contains an empty and vise versa.
Assuming your selectedTemplate structure as follows

```
 {
   "plate": [
       {
          "plateTest": [
              {
                 "columnValues": ['test']
              },
              {
                 "columnValues": []
              }
           ]
       }
    ]

}


export const doesArrayContainEmptyArray = createSelector(
    getTestState,
    (state: TestState) => state.selectedTemplate?.plate.some(p => p.plateTest.some(pt => pt?.columnValues?.length === 0));
);
```